# Unexpected result when operating with uint16_t without explicit casting to float

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, ieee-754

I am doing some operations and found no exact explanation to why I find a specific behaviour.
Context:

- I receive a value (24.2) and then compute some offset and gain
- The result is then send by CAN.

Minimum working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Operations with comas \n");
    
    uint16_t a = (uint16_t)((24.2 - 0)/0.1);        /* 241  Incorrect*/
    uint16_t b = (uint16_t)((24.2 - 0.0)/0.1);      /* 241 Incorrect */
    uint16_t c = (uint16_t)((float)(24.2 - 0)/0.1); /* 242 Correct */
    uint16_t d = (uint16_t)(24.2/0.1);              /* 241 Incorrect*/
    uint16_t e = (uint16_t)(242.0);                 /* 242 Correct */
    
    printf("a %u \n" , a);
    printf("b %u \n" , b);
    printf("c %u \n" , c);
    printf("d %u \n" , d);
    printf("e %u \n" , e);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I know that when using float the value cannot be expressed exactly. With `IEEE-754`
the value of `24.2 is` actually representing `24.200000762939453125` thus the truncation in case `c` and `e` is correct.

Why do case `a`,`b`,`d` yield to the unexpected values? (I know that forcing a cast fixes the issue but I want to understant the cause)

Comment: What's the exact representation of 0.1 as a double?

Comment: According to the C standard, an unsuffixed floating constant has type `double`, not `float`, so all those constants with dots in your code are `double`, and everything else gets promoted to `double`.

Comment: Reopening.  OP is aware of the inexact nature of floating point operations and is questioning what's happening with a particular representation.

Comment: Opinions differ — the problem is the nature of floating point arithmetic and that's the canonical question for "why isn't floating-point arithmetic working as I expect".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C standard, an unsuffixed floating constant has type `double`, not `float`, so all those constants with dots in your code are `double`, and everything else gets promoted to `double`.

Take the following code (notice the suffix `f` on the values of the second expression):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
    uint16_t a = (uint16_t)((24.2 - 0)/0.1);
    uint16_t b = (uint16_t)((24.2f - 0)/0.1f);
    printf("%hu %hu\n", a, b);
}
```

The output is:

```
241 242
```

So the point here is just that different approximations are happening because different floating point precision is being used.

Comment: Selected as answer because conversion to double instead of float results in an understandable behaviour

Answer (score 5):

The constant `24.2` has type `double`, with a value of approximately 24.1999999999999993.  So dividing by 0.1 gives you roughly 241.9999999999999716 and converting this value to an integer type truncates to 241.

When you convert `24.2` to type `float`, the nearest representation is 24.2000007629394531, and dividing by 0.1 gives you 242.0000076293945312 which gets truncated to 242.

Answer (score 4):

Just like 1/3 is a periodic number in decimal,
2/10 is a periodic number in binary, and
1/10 is a periodic number in binary.
These would take infinite storage to accurately store as floating-point numbers.
As such, 24.2 and 0.1 can't be accurately represented as floating-point numbers.
As such, diving one by the other might not produce exactly the correct result. It might be slightly too large or slightly too small.
As such, truncation can have undesirable effects.

On a machine that uses IEEE double-precision numbers for `double`,

```c
24.2       = 24.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
0.1        = 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
24.2 / 0.1 = 241.999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875
```

You got lucky when you used a `float` instead of a `double` (the default for floating-point constants). It happened to be a number slightly larger than the one you wanted.

```c
24.2f       = 24.200000762939453125
0.1         = 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
24.2f / 0.1 = 242.00000762939453125
```

But it could easily have been under as well. Maybe you should utilize rounding instead of truncation?

Answer (score 0):

If the implementation defines `__STDC_IEC_559__`, floating point operations need to conform to Annex F of the specification. In particular, the following items from [C11 F.3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#F.3) should be noted:

> - The `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` operators provide the IEC 60559 add, subtract, multiply, and divide operations.

> - The conversions for floating types provide the IEC 60559 conversions between floating-point precisions.
> - The conversions from integer to floating types provide the IEC 60559 conversions from integer to floating point.
> - The conversions from floating to integer types provide IEC 60559-like conversions but always round toward zero.

In that case, any optimizations performed by the compiler according to the "as-if" rule need to take the above considerations into account, including the rounding errors for each operation. It cannot merely use the mathematical fact that 24.2 / 0.1 = 242.